# How to call a GwtServiceImpl Servlet from external application?

Tags: gwt, serialization, service

I have developed a Gwt application and need now to call its remote service implementation
from another java application. Is there a method that given a List of Java Objects can transform them in a format suitable for invoking the get service servlet?something like:

```
 myObject = .......
  try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://localhost:8080/ppp//org.yournamehere.Main/gwtservice");
         String serialized = <somelibrary.serialize>(myObject);
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(serialize);
           input.setContentType("text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: after  more browsing I found the solution here:    http://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/

Comment: Yes, syncproxy is easier to set up (although I haven't  tried the other suggestion). I did however run into annoying error messages about non-serializable types (usually arrays of primitives) which alledgedly were not on the gwt.rpc whitelist, even though they were.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I haven't tried it the following link seems to be what you are looking for
http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/07/gwtrpccommlayer-extending-gwt-rpc-to-do.html